# How to force brew to install from local formula (without internet access)

Tags: command-line, homebrew

How can I tell brew to skip trying to make calls to the Internet when installing locally?

I have downloaded the brew formula and bottle

```
user@host ~ % ls
wget-1.24.5.json
wget-1.24.5.rb
wget-1.24.5.ventura.bottle.tar.gz
```

According to the manual page `man brew`, you can specify the relative path to the recipe after `brew install`

> ```
>    BREW(1)                              brew                              BREW(1)
>     
>     NAME
>            brew - The Missing Package Manager for macOS (or Linux)
>     
>     SYNOPSIS
>            brew --version
>            brew command [--verbose|-v] [options] [formula] ...
>     ...
>     TERMINOLOGY
>            formula
>                Homebrew package definition that builds from upstream sources
>     ...
>        install formula
>            Install formula.
>     
>            formula is usually the name of the formula to install, but it has other
>            syntaxes which are listed in the SPECIFYING FORMULAE section.
>     ...
>     SPECIFYING FORMULAE
>            Many Homebrew commands accept one  or  more  formula  arguments.  These
>            arguments can take several different forms:
>     
>            The name of a formula
>                   e.g. git, node, wget.
>     
>            The fully-qualified name of a tapped formula
>                   Sometimes  a  formula from a tapped repository may conflict with
>                   one in homebrew/core. You can still  access  these  formulae  by
>                   using a special syntax, e.g. homebrew/dupes/vim or homebrew/ver-
>                   sions/node4.
>     
>            An arbitrary file
>                   Homebrew can install formulae from a local path. It can point to
>                   either a formula file or a bottle. Prefix relative paths with ./
>                   to prevent them from being interpreted as a formula or tap name.
> ```

As described in the documentation above, I execute the following

```
brew reinstall --verbose ./wget-1.24.5.rb
```

Unfortunaelty, the above command attempts to access the Internet. And when `curl` inevitably times-out, rather than using the bottle that's stored in the `$HOMEBREW_CACHE`, it just exits due to the network failure

```
user@host ~ %  brew reinstall --verbose ./wget-1.24.5.rb
curl: (28) Failed to connect to example.com port 9999 after 75004 ms: Couldn't connect to server
Failure while executing; `/usr/bin/env /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/shared/curl --disable --cookie /dev/null --globoff --user-agent Homebrew/4.2.8\ \(Macintosh\;\ Intel\ Mac\ OS\ X\ 12.7.3\)\ curl/8.4.0 --header Accept-Language:\ en --fail --silent --remote-time --output /Users/runner/work/buskill-app/buskill-app/build/deps/api/formula.jws.json --location --disable --cookie /dev/null --globoff --show-error --user-agent Homebrew/4.2.8\ \(Macintosh\;\ Intel\ Mac\ OS\ X\ 12.7.3\)\ curl/8.4.0 --header Accept-Language:\ en --fail --silent --compressed --speed-limit 100 --speed-time 5 https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula.jws.json` exited with 28. Here's the output:
curl: (28) Failed to connect to example.com port 9999 after 75004 ms: Couldn't connect to server
user@host ~ %
```

How can I tell brew *not* to try to download `formula.jws.json` and instead just use the recipe that I've provided locally?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following environment variables

```
export HOMEBREW_VERBOSE=1
export HOMEBREW_DEBUG=1
export HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1
export HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_FROM_API=1
```

In this case, the path to the formula file was wrong, but the output without the debug flag was worthless. Here's the error when I include the `--debug` flag:

```
user@host ~ %  brew reinstall --verbose --debug ./wget-1.24.5.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Cask::CaskLoader::NullLoader): loading ./wget-1.24.5.rb
Warning: No available formula with the name "./wget-1.24.5.rb".
```

I fixed the issue by changing the `./` to the actual path where the `wget-1.24.5.rb` file lives.

And I was able to fix the attempts to download the `formula.jws.json` file with curl with the `HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_FROM_API` environment variable.

Finally, I realized that if you download the bottle, you don't even need the formula. You can link to it directly

```
brew reinstall --verbose --debug path/to/wget-1.24.5.ventura.bottle.tar.gz
```